# Does a varbinary(max) column occupy space if value is null?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a column of type `varbinary(max)`. I have some rows that have data in that column while others do not; they are null.

My question is: does the column with `NULL` also occupy 2 bytes per row? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/08/11/how-sql-server-stores-data-extents-data-pages-data-row-for-in-row-data/ is what you need to read.

There is no data to store, but the metadata will occupy

- 1 bit in the NULL bitmap (each 8 nullable columns = 1 byte)
- 2 bytes in the variable offset array. Unless it is the last column or all columns prior are NULL columns

Comment: Am I correct in saying that this does not hold true if you implement compression or mark the column SPARSE?

Comment: You are correct. Please feel free to edit more details into the answer.